# Infinispan - set per Entity expiration.lifespan

Tags: java, caching, jboss6.x, infinispan, persistence.xml

I have a java web application deployed on Jboss 6.1.0, that uses infinispan 5.2.6.Final.
I'm trying to set a per Entity specific **expiration.lifespan** following this guide

http://infinispan.org/docs/5.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_advanced_configuration_2

for my Entity bean com.myenterprise.myproject.dal.ejb.entity.RefStatus.

The guide states the following:

> You can also override eviction/expiration settings on a per entity/collection 
>   type basis in such way that the overriden settings only afftect that particular 
>   entity (i.e. com.acme.Person) or collection type (i.e. com.acme.Person.addresses). 
>   For example:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.acme.Person.expiration.lifespan" value= "65000"/>
```

So, i've added the following element to my persistence.xml, to reduce the lifespan to 10 milliseconds for test purposes, in order to fine tune it later:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.myenterprise.myproject.dal.ejb.entity.RefStatus.expiration.lifespan" value= "10"/>
```

The setting produces no effects and the lifespan remains the default.

Do you know how I have to set the persistence.xml to successfully override the default expiration lifespan?
Setting the

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.lifespan" value= "10"/>
```

it works, but it affects all entity caches, and it is not what I want.

What follows is my application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myProject_dal_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myProject-DataSource</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.com.myenterprise.myproject.dal.ejb.entity.RefStatus.expiration.lifespan" value= "10"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running within the application server, apart from the entity name, you have to provide the deployment name and unit too. So, all such expiration properties need to be prepended with: `hibernate.cache.infinispan.<warname>.<unitname>.<FQN of entity>...`

In your case, I don't know the name of your deployment, but with the unit and FQN that you mention, something like:

`hibernate.cache.infinispan.<warname>.myProject_dal_PU.com.myenterprise.myproject.dal.ejb.entity.RefStatus.expiration.lifespan`

Comment: Btw, I'm working on updating the documentation to add this missing information.

Comment: nice post/explanantion

Comment: @GalderZamarreño It didnt work with your answer,please find the config change i did. in my case Person entity stays inside demo.war --> my-entity.jar --> com.demo.model.Person.class ...Added following properties to my persistence.xml <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.demo.demo-model.com.demo.model.Person.expiration.lifespan" value="-1"/> For testing pupose i am using jconsole --> statistics --> entries .After some time due to idle time the entities that are store in are getting evicted but we want to stay in the cache without lifespan and timeout(basically no expiration).

Comment: Oops a typo in my previous  comment actually entity stays inside demo.ear-->my-model.jar-->com.demo.model.Person.class

Comment: If you want them to live forever in the overriden configuration, passing -1 should work. If not working, fire up a Remote Debugger on your favourite IDE against your server and put some breakpoints in the `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` class to see what configuration is constructed for those caches, and see whether the overrides are being applied properly.

Answer (score 1):

Spent hours to find correct configuration. Apparently it is as following:

Hibernate property should be in the following format:

`hibernate.cache.infinispan.<prefix>.<full-class-name>.<property-name>` where:

`<prefix>` - by default it is in the name that you see in a sort of JNDI name. In case of Wildfly, it is `ear-name.ear/ejb-jar-name.jar#persistence-unit-name`
However, it can be controlled by `hibernate.cache.region_prefix` property. Set region_prefix to "" and ignore the prefix.

`<property-name>` - String as it appears in `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory` class and in official Infinispan documentation.

In short, official [Infinispan documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html) is correct only when you set `hibernate.cache.region_prefix` to ""