# Infinispan per entity eviction,lifespan controlling using java annotations

Tags: java, infinispan

Infinispan has eviction policy, lifespan for specific to entity. From below question we can make the change in persistence.xml.

[Infinispan - set per Entity expiration.lifespan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058913/infinispan-set-per-entity-expiration-lifespan)

My question is there a way to do this in annotation in that particular entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any such config. The reason for the absence of it is probably because Infinispan (and other cache providers) are general-purpose caching frameworks which in general are not aware of Hibernate second-level caching specifics.

On the other hand, again in general, Hibernate and java.persistence do not interfere with specific cache provider implementations and APIs. That means that a cache provider may even not allow defining expiration policy while still being perfectly able to serve as Hibernate L2 cache.

However, you could define your own annotations and set the Infinispan config values programmatically. You could turn it to an interesting open source project, if there are none so far that do similar thing. :)

Comment: thanks @dragan in this i need to explore a way to set values.