# Infinispan : Cache selective entity for JVM lifetime

Tags: hibernate, caching, infinispan

Environment:

- Wildfly 8.2
- Hibernate 4.3.7
- Infinispan 6.0.2

Hi,

Question :
Is there a way, via annotations or declaratively, we can specify that one of the entity types should be cached for JVM life time.

Background:
We have a JavaEE web app where we want to cache some of the entities (it has only 3 rows in DB table) for JVM life time while having other entities for short time (via central configuration). Reason for life time - the entity has a one-to-Many mapping where the other entities are highly used in the application.

Current Configuration:

persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
```

standalone-full.xml

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
<local-cache name="entity">
    <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
    <transaction mode="NON_XA" locking="OPTIMISTIC"/>
    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
</local-cache>
<query cache ...>

...
```

Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058913/infinispan-set-per-entity-expiration-lifespan).

Basically, you need to add to persistence.xml:

```
<hibernate.cache.infinispan.my.<unitname>.<FQN>.eviction.strategy" value="NONE"/>
<hibernate.cache.infinispan.my.<unitname>.<FQN>.eviction.wake_up_interval" value="-1"/>
```

*unitname* is persistence unit name defined in persistence.xml.

*FQN* is fully qualified name of the entity.

Comment: actually question is to maintain only particular entity in the cache, which may have only few records and not modified at all.Your answer is common to all the entities i guess.

Comment: No, my answer describes how to disable eviction and expiration for certain entities, while keeping default configuration for other entities.

Comment: @Dragan Bozanovic : Thanks for the link. Do you mean we have to specify those values for the specific/intended entities in persistence.xml ? If so, can you paste/suggest the full elements for better understanding.

Comment: The entity resides in a jar file and the deployment path is : deployments/my.ear/entities.jar

Comment: @DraganBozanovic It didnt work with your answer,please find the config change i did.

in my case Person entity stays inside
demo.war --> my-entity.jar --> com.demo.model.Person.class

Added following properties to my persistence.xml
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
 <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.demo.demo-model.com.demo.model.Person.eviction.strategy" value="NONE"/>
   <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.demo.demo-model.com.demo.model.Person.eviction.wake_up_interval" value="-1"/>

For testing pupose i am using jconsole

Comment: In this case, try to omit war name: <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.demo-model.com.demo.model.Person.eviction.‌​strategy" value="NONE"/>  <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.demo-model.com.demo.model.Person.eviction.‌​wake_up_interval" value="-1"/>

Comment: Oops a typo actually entity stays inside demo.ear-->my-model.jar-->com.demo.model.Person.class.

Comment: Ok, could you try to omit the deployment name, anyway?